# How to delete videos in a Youtube playlist and populate with new videos daily

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, youtube

I have the following code that can add videos to a playlist from google sheets using video IDs.

```
function updateYTPlaylist() {

const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
const yt_video_ids = sh.getRange('A2:A'+sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat([1]);

const playlistId = "PL7Ias5xZGXQ9o60ezsHZhl8NkoSm7Tdvj";

yt_video_ids.forEach( vid => 
 
YouTube.PlaylistItems.insert({
  snippet: {
    playlistId: playlistId,
    resourceId: {
      kind: "youtube#video",
      videoId: vid
    }
  }
}, "snippet"));

Utilities.sleep(2000);                                                             
}
```

I would also like to remove the videos that were there the previous day before I add the new ones but am unsure how to go about this.

Comment: finding when videos were added to a playlist is not an option. I can suggest two options: either deleting every single video in the playlist, or create a column B to indicate which videos you want to be deleted. What do you prefer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YouTube API does not provide information regarding when you added a particular video to the playlist. So we can't just delete the videos of the previous day. What I would suggest is to create a new playlist and **everyday** you will run a function (via a time basis trigger) to remove the current videos (that added the previous day) and then add new ones. Therefore, the first part of the script will **clear** your playlist and the second one will **add** new videos to it.

### Clear playlist:

I added the following code snippet to your code that removes every single video from your playlist; or in other words it clears your playlist:

```
const playlistResponse = YouTube.PlaylistItems.list('snippet', {playlistId: playlistId});
const playlistItem = playlistResponse.items;
    playlistItem.forEach(dvid =>
    {YouTube.PlaylistItems.remove(dvid.id);
    Utilities.sleep(2000);}
);
```

### Clear playlist and add new videos:

Therefore, the full code that **clears** a playlist and then **adds** youtube videos based on **A** column of **Sheet1** is the following:

```
function updateYTPlaylist() {

const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
const yt_video_ids  = sh.getRange('A2:A'+sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat([1]);
const playlistId =  "PL7Ias5xZGXQ9o60ezsHZhl8NkoSm7Tdvj";

const playlistResponse = YouTube.PlaylistItems.list('snippet', {playlistId: playlistId});
const playlistItem = playlistResponse.items;
    playlistItem.forEach(dvid =>
    {YouTube.PlaylistItems.remove(dvid.id);
    Utilities.sleep(2000);}
);

yt_video_ids.forEach( avid => 
 
YouTube.PlaylistItems.insert({
  snippet: {
    playlistId: playlistId,
    resourceId: {
      kind: "youtube#video",
      videoId: avid
    }
  }
}, "snippet"));

Utilities.sleep(2000);                                                             
}
```

### Resources:

From the google script editor you need to click on **Resources** => **Advanced Google Services** and then enable **YouTube Data API v3** (as of now this is the newest version).

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm getting error: 

GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to youtube.playlistItems.insert failed with error: Forbidden (line 16, file "Code")

Comment: Check if you have access to the playlist or check if you are from service account etc

Comment: In my case it works. Please check if you are subject to any of these issues : https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/insert

Comment: I got it to run without throwing errors but It's only adding new videos and not deleting.

Comment: I can not replicate your error. Can you see my edited answer? I added a `Utilities.sleep(2000)` . Maybe your playlist has too many videos to delete or smth. @thePOPstream

Comment: @thePOPstream it looks like you haven't enabled YouTube API. Check my answer again, last paragraph..

Comment: Thanks for your help.I enabled YouTube API and it's able to add but still won't remove items.  It's obviously a problem on my end.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/delete?hl=es) is the official documentation for the deletion of an item from a playlist. Unfortunately this http request only deletes one video from the playlist, so you will have to loop through all the id's of the videos the playlist has, deleting each one at a time.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but how do I add it into my script?

Comment: I found a better explanation on another part of the youtube-api documentation. [Here's](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/playlists#playlistItems-delete) the link. I was writing an answer, but the way they explained it was better. Hope it helps